# Error 500 from Google Play Android Developer REST API when getting subscription information

Tags: android, api, httprequest, google-play, subscription

I've followed the complete steps to access the API as described by Google here: 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization.

I have managed to get a refresh token, and am fetching a new access token when my existing one expires.  So now I am trying to get information about a valid subscription using:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/<packageName>/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/purchases/<token>?access_token=<myAccessToken>
```

but the only response I get back is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Has anyone come across this problem before?  I am currently testing with an unpublished application, although the subscription is published so the `packageName`, `subscriptionId` and `token` should be valid.

Comment: Ok, for anyone who is trying to implement Google Subscription Checking from the Google Play Developer API, you will receive the Error 500 response until your application is fully published.

Comment: Does not seem to be the case for me. I'm running it out of the browser with the right access_token

Comment: @dask78 When you say *fully* published, do you mean not just in beta testing? Or does alpha or beta testing suffice?

Comment: @phillip, when you say it does not seem to be the case for you, do you mean that it works when it is not fully published? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

change or add again new internet settings ..500 error is due to early timeout of connections by your wrong or mislead network settings
it cannot be solved by clearing data cache ....